# Help find medieval archer meeting triceratops

Tags: identification-request

I remember as a child seeing an illustration in a book my brother was reading where an archer was pointing a bow at a triceratops but refused to kill it because it might have been the last of its kind. I have no idea the title but the time I saw it was somewhere in the 1990s. Black and white ink as far as I know for the illustration and it might have been a double page.

Comment: Do you have any idea of how the triceratops and the archer met? Such as magic, or time travel, parallel worlds, etc.

Comment: Sorry. I told you all I remember. Even the person who showed me it doesn't remember the book